Expected number of “blocks” in a deck of cards
In a deck of 52 cards, say a ”block” is either any group of one or more cards all of the same suit found at the beginning (or the end) of the deck, followed (or anteceded) by a card of a different suit, or any other group of cards, also all of the same suit, found between two cards not of that same suit.
What is the expected number of “blocks” in a shuffled deck of 52 cards?

The number of blocks is just 1 plus the number of adjacent pairs which don't share a suit. The expected number is easy by linearity (you can for example sum over the 51 positions where a switch of suit can occur, or over the 52*39/2 pairs of cards of different suits which can be neighbours).
